# Where is user's cron job stored after "crontab -e"?

Tags: linux

I'm root, and I saw there are a lot of contents in `/etc/crontab`, which I thought is the root's cron job configurations. When I use `crontab -e`, I saw nothing in the editor; after I quit `crontab -e`, what I added was not found in `/etc/crontab`. So, where is root's cron job configuration stored? And other users?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is stored in the directory:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

Containing one file per user.

From `man crontab` (at least on my Ubuntu 13):

> There  is  one file for each user's crontab under the
>   /var/spool/cron/crontabs directory. Users are not allowed to edit the
>   files under that directory directly to ensure that only users allowed
>   by the system to run periodic tasks can add them, and only
>   syntactically correct crontabs will be written there.  This is
>   enforced by having the directory writable only by the crontab group
>   and configuring crontab command with the setgid bid set for that
>   specific group.

Comment: This is quite helpful, but I'll mention that the storage location could vary as it's not part of the interface.  So certainly if you cared about lots of linux distributions and other unixes, it could be elsewhere.  But certainly checking your local manpage is a good start.

Comment: also similar to _incrontab -e_ command … /var/spool/incron/$USER

Answer (score 10):

It is distribution-dependant, but mostly it is in `/var/spool/crontab/<username>`.

Answer (score 4):

For those looking for Fedora/CentOS/RHES, it's:

```
/var/spool/cron/<username>
```